# Actions on Google - CLI (gactions) not found

Tags: git, powershell, actions-on-google

I'm trying to install the [gactions CLI](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli) but I'm having some problems.

I downloaded it for windows from the link above. I run the .exe file, see a cmd screen, and then it closes.

I've added the environment variable as well, but every time I use gactions on Powershell or the Git Shell, I get the same 'gactions: command not found' error.

Totally new to all this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Download [gactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli)

copy downloaded gactions and put into a local Project folder

and  then go to your project directory cd "**project directory**"

run following commands :

```
$ chmod +x gactions

$ ./gactions init
```

it will create ***action.json*** into your folder

Answer (score 2):

Do not double click on the gaction.exe file use it on cmd as mentioned below.

```
 D:\Action_google_app>gaction.exe init  #to create action.json(default)
```

You can use all commands for below link.

https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with the cmd closing, you can run the the cmd terminal from the run app (windows + R) and typing the command

```
cmd /K
```

to prevent from closing.

The instructions are confusing because there is no "unpacking" of the CLI excusable file. Just cd to the directory the gactions.exe is placed and invoke commands by referring to the program, e.g.

```
C:\actions-sdk>gactions -help
```